# Proof that $a^n$ is well-defined

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider a non-empty set $X$ and an associative operation $*$ on $X$ with identity element $e$. For $a\in X$ define
$$a^0:=e,\quad a^{n+1}:=a^n*a,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Then $a^n$ is well-defined because of the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $a\in X$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}^{\times}$, let $V_n:X^n \to X$ be a function. Then there is a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=V_{n+1}(f(0),f(1),\ldots f(n))$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Question**:
How does the theorem prove that $a^n$ is well-defined? Why do we need the theorem at all? Intuitively, I see that $a^n$ is well-defined without even using the theorem, but I don't know what could go wrong with the definition and how to get rid of my intuition.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $f(0)=a$? Rather than $f(0)=e$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The textbook says $f(0)=a$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But it doesn't matter what you call $f(0)$ as long as $f(0)\in X$.

Comment: If you "see that $a^n$ is well defined without using the theorem" then you should write down the existence proof of such a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$. Note that a defintion may not include any version of "and so on" or any "$\dots$". The existence of such a function is not easy to establish, that's why we have the theorem about functions defined by recursion.

Comment: @ancientmathematician However, $f(n+1)=V_{n+1}(f(0),f(1),\ldots f(n))$ does include "$\ldots$"

Comment: @Vestoo: but not as part of the *definition*, the theorem states "there exists a function with the property that ..."  Essentially that's the whole point.

Comment: @Vestoo We can eliminate this $\ldots$ from the definition as follows. Consider some $n$. Let $t \in A^n$ be the unique tuple such that for all $i$ s.t. $0 \leq i \leq n$, $t_i = f(i)$. Then $f(n + 1) = V_n(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to get rid of your intuition--that's a good intuition to have. I think most 19th century mathematicians would, like you, have regarded this fact as obvious without a formal proof.

The issue here is "definition by induction" vs. "proof by induction". In the 20th century, partly because of mathematical logic, people started to take a closer look at this. If you want to give a *formal* proof that definition-by-induction is legitimate, you'll need something like the theorem you quote.

The intuition behind the statement of the theorem: A definition by induction says how to obtain the value of a function $f(n+1)$ from the list of all previous values $f(0),\ldots,f(n)$. It's claimed that this is sufficient to deterine $f$ for all values, provided we're given the starting value $f(0)$. In other words, there is a unique function that fits the inductive definition.

You can see the similarity with proof by induction. The theorem you quote is a formal statement of the previous paragraph.

In this instance, a couple of things make matters more confusing. First we have a notation conflict. The $a$ of the $V_n$ theorem is $e$ in your example, and the $a$ in your example has nothing to do with $a$ of the theorem. Rewrite the $V_n$ theorem to use $e$ instead of $a$. That should help.

Second, in your example the new value $f(n+1)$ depends *only* on the one previous value $f(n)$ (and of course the base $a$). So a weaker version of the $V_n$ theorem would work, where $V_n:X\to X$, and $f(n+1)=V_n(f(n))$. But you can use the stronger version just by ignoring the inputs $f(0),\ldots f(n-1)$.

A couple more remarks about the need for the theorem. Nowadays the "gold standard" of rigor is proof in a formal theory, like Peano Arithmetic (PA) or Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF). In practice one rarely does this (too painful), but it's still theoretically important that such proofs *could* be done. In this context, something like the $V_n$ theorem is needed. As someone noted in the comments, the equivalent of "and so on", or "$\ldots$", isn't allowed.

As for the "$\ldots$" in $f(0),\ldots,f(n)$, this is an issue. ZF and PA deal with it in different ways. In ZF, $f(0),\ldots,f(n)$ is replaced with a function whose domain is $\{i\in\mathbb{N}|0\leq i\leq n\}$. (No "$\ldots$"s!). In PA, you need a very clever trick, due to Gödel [(the $\beta$ function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function).

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, let $V_n\colon X^n\longrightarrow X$ be the function defined by$$V_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=a*a_n.$$Let $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow X$ be the function such that $f(0)=a$ and that$$f(n+1)=V_{n+1}\bigl(f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(n)\bigr).$$And now you can say that$$a^n=\begin{cases}e&\text{ if }n=0\\f(n-1)&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$since$$a^{n+1}=a*a^n=V_n\bigl(f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)\bigr)=f(n).$$So, now the sequence $(a^n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is well-defined.

Comment: But how do you know that $V_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)=V_n(f(0),f(1),\ldots ,f(n-1))$ before knowing that $a^n=f(n-1)$? I don't understand how you got $a*a^n=V_n (f(0),f(1),\ldots f(n-1))$ in the last line.

Comment: Where did I state that $V_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=V_n\bigl(f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)\bigr)$? I don't even understand what it means.

Comment: It follows from transitivity of equality. $a*a^n=V_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)$ (first equation you wrote) and $a*a^n=V_n(f(0),f(1),\ldots f(n-1))$ (last equation you wrote).

Comment: Actually, the first equality that I wrote was $a*a_n=V_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: Oh you're right. Sorry.